# Routing subdomains with querystrings

Tags: .htaccess, routing, subdomain

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)(/)?$ index.php?controller=main&function=$1&arguments=$2 [NC,L]
```

I can go `mysite.com/one/two`
to go `main->one(two)`

I'd like to route subdomain requests the same way.

how would I setup a rule like this for `api.mysite.com` to hit the following?

```
controller=api&function=$1&arguments=$2 [NC,L]
```

(allowing me to go api.mysite.com/one/two to hit api->one(two))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)(/)?$  \
  index.php?controller=%1&function=$1&arguments=$2 [NC,L]
```

mod_rewrite allows the use of %N, where N is 1..9, to match bracketed patterns from the previous `RewriteCond`, so `%1` is used to replace in the `api` domain prefix from the rewriteCond

Comment: trying: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com` and
`RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php?controller=%1&function=index [NC,L]` to get the root of api.mysite.com.. seems to not be working.. if I go api.mysite.com/api it will work though.. when i do `RewriteRule ^api(/)?$ index.php?controller=%1&function=index [NC,L]`

Comment: Nevermind. Ended up being an ordering issue

Answer (score 0):

I did end up finding that it was just easier to make a new virtual host and point it at a new, api-specific htaccess file:

```
ServerName api.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/host/mysite.com/html
AccessFileName .api.htaccess # <-- this did the trick
```